# to display popup using show method here popUpDiv is a div

Tags: javascript, html

can anyone suggest an alternative method for show() in JavaScript that supports in ie11 s[enter image description here][1]ince show/hide not supporting it...

```js
function displayPopUp(xPopUp,yPopUp,wPopUp,lPopUp,message) 
{
 showDivCache();

 
    var oPopup=document.getElementById("popUpDiv");
  
  
 oPopup.style.backgroundColor = "#D6D6D6";
 oPopup.style.border = "solid black 3px";
 oPopup.innerHTML = "<TABLE width='100%' height='100%'><TR valign='middle'><TD align='center'><B>"+message+"</B></TD></TR></TABLE>";
    **oPopup.show(popUpX, popUpY, popUpW, popUpL, document.body);**
 window.onfocus = redisplayPopUp;
 
 var size=0;

 var tabAllData=document.all;
 if (tabAllData.document!=null)
  size=document.all.length;
 for (i = 0;i<size;i++)
 {
   fldObj = tabAllData[i];
   fldObj.onfocus=redisplayPopUp;
 }
 return true;
```

Comment: Use [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/).

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember problems with IE11. How ever you can acheive this by many ways with jquery.

```
$('#id').toggle()

$('#id').fadeIn()  
$('#id').fadeOut()
```

Using css

```
.hidden{
display: none;}

$('#id').addClass("hidden");
```

Or even

```
 document.getElementById("id").style.visibility = "hidden"; 

 //this one will remove the allocated space 
 document.getElementById("id").style.display = "none";
```